# Embed Flash Object by bypassing rules?

Tags: html, flash, iframe

i want to embed a youtube video to a profile page, but the social system does not allow embedding flash objects

now i wonder if theres a possibility to bypass this rule, the first thing i was thinking of was embedding an iframe to a page that links the object.

sadly the social network also disallows iframes.

do you have any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I added the code sample you requested

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using javascript to generate the flash object?

I use swfobject (http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/)

### Html

```
<div id="youTubVideo">
Loading You Tube Video
</div>
```

### Script

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="swfobject.js>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var youTubeClip = new SWFObject("http://www.youtube.com/v/G3NueKXS6dk&hl=en&fs=1", "youTubVideo", "425", "344", "8", "#ffffff");
    youTubeClip.addParam("allowFullScreen", "true");
    youTubeClip.write("youTubVideo");
</script>
```

Comment: but how can i add the youtube vid in this code? the vid i want has this adress, the codeis too long to insert, im sorry:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AWggPLXeOkU

Comment: thanks, but another problem, i am not able to acces the head of the page, i can only access the body.